# concatenating strings - how do you do this one in a clean way?

Tags: c, string

I am writing a C extension for PHP and there I have to build up a string based on some substrings. Currently it looks like this:

```
spprintf(
    &bucket_list_url, 
    strlen(host) + 1 + sizeof(port) + 1 + strlen(prefix) +strlen("?buckets=true"),
    "%s:%d/%s?buckets=true",
    host, 
    port,
    prefix
);
```

It works, but looks horrible and is possibly difficult to maintain. Is there a more cleaner way for safely concatenating these strings together?

I am a beginner in C, as you've probably noticed, so I couldn't come up with any cleaner solution so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using the GNU C runtime (glibc), you can use the [`asprintf(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/asprintf) function to format a string to a dynamically allocated buffer.  That way, you don't have to worry about having a large enough buffer.  For example:

```
// Error checking omitted for expository purposes
char *bucket_list_url;
asprintf(&bucket_list_url, "%s:%d/%s?buckets=true", host, port, prefix);
...  // do stuff
free(bucket_list_url);
```

If you're not using glibc, you can still use [`snprintf(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf), but you have to guess at the buffer length.  If you guess wrong, you have to allocate a bigger buffer and try again.

Comment: With `snprintf` you can guess once, but if it fails you don't "try again" because it tells you how much space it needed. (Of course, you can always throw your first guess away with `snprintf(NULL, 0, ...)` but perhaps for a given situation you could make an educated guess for what you might need and save some cycles.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are meaning to use snprintf:

```
char bucket_list_url[1024];

snprintf(bucket_list_url, sizeof(bucket_list_url), "%s:%d/%s?buckets=true", host, port, prefix);
```

The second parameter of snprintf is the length of the first parameter in bytes, not the length of the string you are expecting to get after the function call.

Answer (score 0):

Here's little snippet I wrote a while back. It's perhaps a little silly, but maybe it's what you're looking for. Note: it's not the most efficient, because it does two `vsnprintf`s. The first is to determine what the length of the buffer should be.

```
char * new_string_from_format(const char * fmt, ...) {
  int size;
  char * string_buffer;

  assert(fmt != NULL);
  assert(strlen(fmt) > 0);

  //  first determine the length the buffer should be
  va_list args;
  va_start(args, fmt);
  size = vsnprintf(NULL, 0, fmt, args) + 1;
  va_end(args);
  assert(size > 0);


  string_buffer = new char[size];
  va_start(args, fmt);
  vsnprintf(string_buffer, size, fmt, args);
  va_end(args);

  return string_buffer;
}
```

It's probably similar to glibc's asprintf, (but doesn't require glibc.)

Comment: The question is tagged C, not C++. You might want to clean that up a bit. (And if your C (or C++) compiler supports a few C99 features, make a `v` version of this and use `va_copy` instead of `va_end` / `va_start`) (And wouldn't it be more efficient to use `std::string::reserve` and use the `std::string`'s buffer instead of making your own and throwing it away?)

Comment: Good point; I took out the C++. And thanks for the other suggestions as well. I'll consider adding them to my own code and if all goes well I'll update this.